# many to many normalization

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, database-normalization

I'm studying Database normalization and I just can't understand one thing.
Suppose we have a Many-to-Many relation. We have a table Course and we have a table Student. Multiple students may take multiple courses.

Suppose we have a "transition" table Course_Student that stores only primary keys of a student and a course he has chosen.

My task is to make all tables in 3NF and if some table is not in 3NF then to explain why.

My question is: are these tables already in 3NF and I'm especially concerned about the "transition" table.

Thanks so much!

```
Course
id title
1  Math
2  Programming

Student
id name
1  John Stevens
2  Jack Ryan

Course_Student
course_id student_id
1         1
1         2
2         1


CREATE TABLE Course(
id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
title varchar(100) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE Student(
id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
name varchar(50) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE Course_Student(
course_id int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Course,
student_id int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Student
)
```

Comment: You see, my task is to define which normal form each table is in. For some reason I'm having doubts whether Course_Student table is in the 3rd normal form.

Comment: dont forget the primary key, id column on course is PK, id column on student is PK, course_id and student_id column is compound key (multiple primary keys)

Comment: It is in 3NF, the primary key in that table is (course_id, student_id) so it doesn't have any attributes.

Comment: Is this homework?  If so, you should state that.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding of Normalization, your tables are already in 3.5 NF (BCNF). The design of your table is great.

Over normalization can be bad sometimes but in your case it seems perfectly sane.

For the Table (Course_Student)

Primary Key should be `(course_id, student_id)`

with 2 foreign keys, referencing the two table :) !

Answer (score 1):

Assessing normal form is something that is done to a database **design** that includes, for each table, the applicable **functional dependencies**.

Absent an explicit statement of the latter, all dependencies can only be assumed to be on (all) the keys, and hence the design can only be assumed to satisfy (at least) BCNF, by definition.

Comment: Interestingly though in this particular case sufficient info has been given to deduce 6NF (not that anything has been demonstrated).